# Error when running .ExecuteStoreCommand twice in one ActionResult "Parameter already used"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parameters, actionresult, sqlclient

I get this error, but I don't know how to clear the command object if at all possible. The idea I found on StackOverflow and am using here of 2 different parameter variables still remains glued to the first execute command. At worse I think I could split this ActionResult in half by calling two functions, each with it's own .ExecuteStoreCommand. Unless someone knows how to clear the parameter in EF?
In ADO.NET it is simpler: Command.Paramters.Clear()

System.ArgumentException: The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection.

```
var @ThisBatch= new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("ThisBatch",System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,3,"BactiBatchID");
@ThisBatch.Value= Session["ThisBatch"];

var sql ="UPDATE dbo.BactiBatches SET BatchStatus = 'C' WHERE BactiBatchID= @ThisBatch";

_db.ExecuteStoreCommand(sql, ThisBatch);


var @ThisBatch2 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("ThisBatch2", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 3, "Batch_ID");
@ThisBatch2.Value = Session["ThisBatch"];

sql = "";
sql = "UPDATE dbo.BactiBucket SET RecvDate = GetDate() WHERE Batch_ID= @ThisBatch2";


_db.ExecuteStoreCommand(sql, ThisBatch);


return RedirectToAction("AddColiform");
```

Edit/Update:
Ok, I was able to do it like this. Not sure if there is a better answer so I will wait before answering my own question:

```
_db.ExecuteStoreCommand("UPDATE dbo.BactiBatches SET BatchStatus = 'C' WHERE BactiBatchID= {0}", Session["ThisBatch"]);
_db.ExecuteStoreCommand("UPDATE dbo.BactiBucket SET RecvDate = GetDate() WHERE Batch_ID={0}", Session["ThisBatch"]);

Session["ThisBatch"] = 0;
```

Comment: I guess the second `_db.ExecuteStoreCommand(sql, ThisBatch);` should be `_db.ExecuteStoreCommand(sql, ThisBatch2);`?

Comment: Oh, maybe so. If it was a snake it would have bit me. I will test this tomorrow and thanks ekad.

Comment: Hey ekad, you are correct. Could you turn your comment into an Answer and I will accept it.
I now have 2 ways to do this which is fine by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the second update command

```
var @ThisBatch2 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("ThisBatch2", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 3, "Batch_ID");
@ThisBatch2.Value = Session["ThisBatch"];

sql = "";
sql = "UPDATE dbo.BactiBucket SET RecvDate = GetDate() WHERE Batch_ID= @ThisBatch2";

_db.ExecuteStoreCommand(sql, ThisBatch);
```

I think you actually want to use `ThisBatch2` instead of `ThisBatch` as the second parameter of `_db.ExecuteStoreCommand` method, so change it to `ThisBatch2`.

```
var @ThisBatch2 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("ThisBatch2", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 3, "Batch_ID");
@ThisBatch2.Value = Session["ThisBatch"];

sql = "";
sql = "UPDATE dbo.BactiBucket SET RecvDate = GetDate() WHERE Batch_ID= @ThisBatch2";

_db.ExecuteStoreCommand(sql, ThisBatch2);
```